# Integration along the diagnal

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that $f(x),g(y):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are real valued functions. Suppose further that $ \chi $ is supported on the diagonal of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ where $ x=y $. Does it follow that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} f(x)g(y)\chi(x,y) dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(z) g(z) \chi(z,z) dz?
\end{equation}

Comment: I think you meant $\chi(z, z)$ in the second integral. Is $\chi$ supposed to be a function? In that case it doesn't follow. We are integrating along a set of measure $0$, so the integral is $0$. It means that it doesn't have to follow in general (when $\chi$ is a measure).

Comment: Yeah you are right. Sorry, let me fix that. $\chi$ is meant to be a function supported on the diagonal indeed.

Comment: Lebesgue integration is more general than Riemann integration. What happens for Lebesgue integrals, must happen for Riemann integrals. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x)g(x)\chi(x, y)dxdy = \int_{\{(x, x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}} f(x)g(y)\chi(x, y)dxdy$. Since $\{(x, x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ has 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure $0$, whole integral must be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\chi (x,y)=1$ if $x=y$, $0$ if $x \neq y$ and $f=g=I_{(0,1)}$ then  LHS $=0$ and RHS $=1$.